# Let $L=\{a^nb^nc^n | n\geq 0\}$ , then $\overline{L}$ is context free

Tags: formal-grammars

I need help with this problem.
I proved that $L$ is not context free (using Ogden's lemma), but I can't prove that $\overline{L}$ is context free. I'm thinking about a proof by cases (if $\#(a)=\#(b) \neq \#(c)$ or something else) but the proof could be so extensive.

Comment: Has been asked before many times.